# Get count of horizontal variables based on condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame in R that looks like:

Data<-

```
RefId       Status     Year       PS Score      Price    Code   StatusID
IU-1        Approved   2020       -             -        23     FT
IU-1        Cancel     2020       -             -        21     CT
IU-2        Approved   2020       -             NA       13     FT
IU-3        Approved   2019       NA            -        40     FT
```

I need to count the unique `RefID` whose `Status` is approved and count of each `-`, `NA` and Not Null values of variables starting from column 4 group by year.

Where 1st row corresponding to the year value have the unique count of `RefID` below that row it would be sum of count or respective variables.

Required output format-

```
Year         Unique_Count    PS Score       Price        Code       StatusID
2020         2               NA             NA           NA         NA                
NA           0               0              1            0          0
Having "-"   2               2              1            0          0
Not Null     2               0              0            2          2
2019         1               NA             NA           NA         NA
NA           1               1              0            0          0
Having "-"   1               0              1            0          0
Not Null     2               0              0            1          1
```

Comment: What is `Not Null` -? Is it only `NA`?

Comment: @akrun: That is other than "-" and `NA`.

Comment: So the `Having `-` is a separate one?

Comment: Having "-" means count where we found - and NA means where value is NA and rest will come under "Not Null" variable.

Comment: Can you check whether the Unique_Count columns values are correct for Having '-' and NA for 2019

Comment: I am not sure how you got `NA` 1 on Unique_Count for 2019

Comment: @akrun- `Unique_Count` corresponding to Year Value is unique count of `RefId` group by that year having status as `Appoved`. All the rows below the year value are sum of column 3,4,5 & 6 values.

Comment: If I check the RefIf wherfe status is approved, there is no NA in that RefId column by year

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230861/discussion-between-user9211845-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data showed, create a logical column 'i1' where 'Status' is 'Approved' (or may `filter` as well), then grouped by 'Year', `summarise` (in the new version of `dplyr` - summarise can return more than 1 row per group), create a 'categ' column that specifies the various categories of frequencies, then the 'Unique_Count' as a `list` of values that returns the number of distinct (`n_distinct`) elements of 'RefId' based on 'i1', count of NA elements (`sum(is.na(`), count of elements with `-` (`str_detect(...`), count of Not NULL (no NA - `sum(!is.na(`).  Similarly, we loop `across` the columns from PSScore to StatusID, does similar counts in a `list`, then `unnest` the `list` elements and remove the 'Year' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(i1 = Status == 'Approved') %>%
    group_by(Year) %>% 
    summarise(categ = c(first(Year), "NA", "Having -", "Not NULL"),
         Unique_Count = list(n_distinct(RefId[i1]), 
                sum(is.na(RefId[i1])), sum(str_detect(RefId[i1], '-')),
                sum(!is.na(RefId[i1]))), 
       across(PSScore:StatusID, ~ list(NA_real_, sum(is.na(.[i1])), 
         sum(.[i1] %in% '-'), sum(!(is.na(.[i1])| .[i1] %in% '-')))), 
         .groups = 'drop') %>%
    unnest(names(.)[-1]) %>% 
    select(-Year)
# A tibble: 8 x 6
#  categ    Unique_Count PSScore Price  Code StatusID
#  <chr>           <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 2019                1      NA    NA    NA       NA
#2 NA                  0       1     0     0        0
#3 Having -            1       0     1     0        0
#4 Not NULL            1       0     0     1        1
#5 2020                2      NA    NA    NA       NA
#6 NA                  0       0     1     0        0
#7 Having -            2       2     1     0        0
#8 Not NULL            2       0     0     2        2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(RefId = c("IU-1", "IU-1", "IU-2", "IU-3"), 
Status = c("Approved", 
"Cancel", "Approved", "Approved"), Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2019L), PSScore = c("-", "-", "-", NA), Price = c("-", "-", NA, 
"-"), Code = c(23L, 21L, 13L, 40L), StatusID = c("FT", "CT", 
"FT", "FT")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```